# Oracle SQL : FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: sql, oracle

my query as follows.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT EmpID, EmpName, EmpSalary,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EmpSalary DESC)
    FROM dbo.Salary
)
SELECT EmpID, EmpName, EmpSalary
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = @8thRow
```

I am getting error as

> Error report -
>   SQL Error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
>   00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected".

Can someone explain what is wrong with the code?

Comment: I think you are missing some of the code would you please include the initial part of the code as it is difficult to get as to what your query is

Comment: You can't assign a variable `RN =  ...` like that in Oracle

Answer (score 0):

Wrong syntax; an example based on Scott's schema:

```
SQL> select ename, sal from emp order by sal;

ENAME             SAL
---------- ----------
SMITH             920
JAMES             950
ADAMS            1100
WARD             1250
MARTIN           1250
MILLER           1300
TURNER           1500    -- 8th  --> you need this one
ALLEN            1600
CLARK            2450
BLAKE            2850
JONES            2975    -- ...
SCOTT            3000    -- 3rd
FORD             3000    -- 2nd
KING            10000    -- 1st, when sort is DESCending

14 rows selected.

SQL> with cte as
  2    (select empno, ename, sal,
  3       row_number() over (order by sal desc) rn
  4     from emp
  5    )
  6  select empno, ename, sal
  7  from cte
  8  where rn = 8;

     EMPNO ENAME             SAL
---------- ---------- ----------
      7844 TURNER           1500

SQL>
```

Comment: Exactly you cant set `Rn=` you need to replace like the above because `=` in sql means to check for a condition not to assign a value there is `:=` operator for assigning values to variable can try if it works.